# Creating different arrays through loops

Tags: arrays, file, perl, loops

Is it possible to create different named arrays while looping in Perl? What I need to do is open some files from `@ARGV` and put their data in separate arrays in one loop, for example: `1.txt` in `@first_array`, `2.txt` in `@second_array` and etc. Is it possible and if yes, what would be the best approach?

**EDIT:**

I think I'm getting closer, since `Data::Dumper` shows a correct structure of what I need, but it doesn't show the values of the files, instead, it shows this:

```
$VAR1 = {
      'skai.txt' => [
                      \*{'::$fh'},
                      $VAR1->{'skai.txt'}[0],
                      $VAR1->{'skai.txt'}[0],
                      $VAR1->{'skai.txt'}[0]
                    ],
      'numb.txt' => [
                      \*{'::$fh'},
                      $VAR1->{'numb.txt'}[0],
                      $VAR1->{'numb.txt'}[0],
                      $VAR1->{'numb.txt'}[0]
                    ]
    };
```

Each file consists of 4 numbers. My code looks like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $data = {};

foreach my $arg(@ARGV){
    if(open(my $fh, $arg)){
        $data->{$arg}=[];
        while(<$fh>){
            chomp;
            push @{$data->{$arg}}, $fh;
        }
    close($fh);
    }
}

print Dumper $data;
```

What is the meaning of `\*{'::$fh'}`?

Comment: Do you *really* need the arrays to be named `first_array`, `second_array`, etc? Or do you just want to make sure each file gets loaded into a separate array?

Comment: Not sure, what I really need to do is to later access elements from different arrays with the same indexes(I need to multiply first_array[0] with second_array[0], first_array[1] with second_array[1] and etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you don't really need the individual arrays to be named `@first_array`, `@second_array`, etc. You just want to keep them separate.

In that case, why not just have an array of arrays? Like so:

```
my @array_of_arrays;

for my $f (@ARGV) {
   my @array = load_file($f);
   push @array_of_arrays, \@array;
}
```

Note: `load_file` is just a placeholder for some function you presumably have to read a file into an array.

Then later on...

```
array_of_arrays[0][0] * array_of_arrays[1][0] * ... * array_of_arrays[$N][0]
```

**Update**: You need to pass a *reference* to `@array` to the `push` function, rather than just `@array`. Otherwise, `push` will create a flattened array containing all of the elements of each individual array. Thanks to @Garo and @mob for pointing this out.

Comment: Incorrect, `push @array_of_arrays, @array` will just add all values in @array to @array_of_arrays. The result here will be one large array and not an array of arrays

Comment: @Garo Not according to `Data::Dumper`. That's weird. I think you're actually correct, but now I can't explain why `Data::Dumper` shows an array of arrays.

Comment: `Data::Dumper` would show an array of arrays if the return value of `load_file` was an array reference, and every assignment to `@array` made it an array with a single array reference element.

Answer (score 2):

This is the strange part of your code:

```
push @{$data->{$arg}}, $fh;
```

`$fh` is the filehandle. That's why you're getting that output. Each time around the loop, you're adding exactly the same value (the filehandle) to your data structure.

```
'skai.txt' => [
               \*{'::$fh'},
               $VAR1->{'skai.txt'}[0],
               $VAR1->{'skai.txt'}[0],
               $VAR1->{'skai.txt'}[0]
             ],
```

The first value (`\*{'::$fh'}`) is just Data::Dumper's slightly over-complicated way of saying "a reference to the filehandle that is stored in `$fh`". The three subsequent values are Data::Dumper saying "this is a value that already appears in this data structure, so instead of writing the value out again, I'll just show you a reference to the existing value".

I think that if you change that line to:

```
push @{$data->{$arg}}, $_;
```

Then you'll get something a lot closer to what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, what you should use is arrayreferences inside a hash, hashref, array or arrayref.

Below is how i would do it (a hashref of arrayrefs):

```
my $data={};  #a hashref where all data will end up
foreach my $currentfile (@ARGV){
  open (my $filehandle ,$currentfile);
  $data->{$currentfile}=[];  #a empty arrayref inside the hashref for every file
  while(<$fh>) {
    push @{$data->{$currentfile}}; #add lines to the arrayref
  }
  close $filehandle;
}
```

Result: all data will be available in the form `$data->{FILENAME}->[LINENUMBER COUNTING FROM 0]`.

Example: line 7 of file "foo.txt" will now be in `$data->{foo.txt}->[6]`

Depending on your actual purpose an array or arrayref might be a better choice then a hashref (If you don't care about the filenames but care about which number of argument they are in `@ARGV`). But this is not entirely clear in your question

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped a lot. I edited my question after adding Data Dumper, maybe you know where is the problem?

Comment: Don't need the line `$data->{$currentfile}=[];`  -- the arrayref will be _autovivfied_ (created automatically when needed) in `push @{$data->{$currentfile}};`